# AMQP.Net Lite Integration Tests

Tags: amqpnetlite

Is it possible to use AMQP.Net Lite as an in-process server replacement for Azure Service Bus in local integration tests? I can't find any examples for connecting to a local server using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, and when I try to set it up myself it always times out trying to connect.